# Binary search—Can't use string "1" as a symbol ref while strict refs is in use

Tags: perl, binary-search

I've been browsing over the already answered questions regarding this error message.

I am trying to solve a problem from the [Rosalind web site](http://rosalind.info/problems/locations/) that looks for some indexes using a binary search.

When my subroutine finds the number it seems to ignore it, and if I try to print the `$found` variable, it gives me the error

> Can't use string "1" as a symbol ref while strict refs is in use

The code is this

```
sub binarysearch
{
  my $numbertolook = shift;
  my @intarray=@_;
  my $lengthint = scalar @intarray;
  my @sorted = sort {$a <=> $b} @intarray;
  #print $numbertolook, " " , @sorted, "\n";
  my $low=0;
  my $high=$lengthint-1;
  my $found =undef;
  my $midpoint;
     while ($low<$high)
     {
     $midpoint=int(($low+$high)/2);
     #print $midpoint, " ",$low," ", $high, " ", @sorted, "\n";
        if ($numbertolook<$sorted[$midpoint])
        {
            $high=$midpoint;
        }
        elsif ($numbertolook>$sorted[$midpoint])
        {
           $low=$midpoint;
        }
        elsif ($numbertolook==$sorted[$midpoint])
        {
           $found=1;
           print $found "\n";
           last;
        }
        if ($low==$high-1 and $low==$midpoint)
        {
            if ($numbertolook==$sorted[$high])
            {
                $found=1;
                print $found "\n";
                last;
            }
            $low=$high;
        }

     }

  return $found;

}
```

Comment: Please show how you are calling `binarysearch`. I can work out how it *should* look from what you have shown, but you need to show your calling code as well as any data files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to help

First of all, as simple as it may seem, a binary search is quite difficult to code correctly. The main reason is that it's a hotbed of off-by-one errors, which are so prevalent that they have their own [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error)

The issue is that an array containing, say, the values `A` to `Z` will have 26 elements with indices 0 to 25. I think FORTRAN bucks the trend, and Lua, but pretty much every other language has the first element of an array at index zero

A zero base works pretty well for everything until you start using [*divide and conquer* algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms). Merge Sort as well as Binary Search are such algorithms. Binary search goes

- Is it in the first half?
- If so then search the first half further
- Else search the second half further

The hard part is when you have to decide when you've found the object, or when you need to give up looking. Splitting data in two nearly-halves is easy. Knowing when to stop is *hard*

It's highly efficient for sorted data, but the problem comes when implementing it that, if we do it properly, we have to deal with all sorts of weird index bases beyond zero or one.

Suppose I have an array

```
my @alpha = 'A' .. 'Q'
```

If I `print scalar @alpha` I will see 17, meaning the array has seventeen elements, indexed from 0 to 16

Now I'm looking for `E` in that array, so I do a binary search, so I want the "first half" and the "second half" of `@alpha`. If I add 0 to 16 and divide by 2 I get a neat "8", so the middle element is at index 8, which is `H`

But wait. There are 17 elements, which is an odd number, so if we say the first eight (`A` .. `H`) are left of the middle and the last eight (`I` .. `Q`) are right of the middle then surely the "middle" is `I`?

In truth this is all a deception, because a binary search will work however we partition the data. In this case *binary* means two parts, and although the search would be more efficient if those parts could be equal in size it's not necessary for the algorithm to work. So it can be the first third and the last two-thirds, or just the first element and the rest

That's why using `int(($low+high)/2)` is fine. It rounds down to the nearest integer so that with our 17-element array `$mid` is a usable 8 instead of 8.5

But your code still has to account for some unexpected things. In the case of our 17-element array we have calculated the middle index to be 8. So indexes 0 .. 7 are the "first half" while 8 .. 16 are the "second half", and the middle index is where the second half starts

But didn't we round the division *down*? So in the case of an odd number of elements, shouldn't our mid point be at the end of the first half, and not the start of the second? This is an arcane off-by-one error, but let's see if it still works with a simple even number of elements

```
@alpha = `A` .. `D`
```

The start and and indices are 0 and 3; the middle index is `int((0+3)/2)` == 1. So the first half is 0..1 and the second half is 2 .. 3. That works fine

But there's still a lot more. Say I have to search an array with two elements `X` and `Y`. That has two clear halves, and I'm looking for `A`, which is before the middle. So I now search the one-element list `X` for `A`. The minimum and maximum elements of the target array are both zero. The mid-point is `int((0+0)/2)` == 0. So what happens next?

It is similar but rather worse when we're searching for `Z` in the same list. The code has to be exactly right, otherwise we will be either searching off the end of the array or checking the last element again and again

Saving the worst for last, suppose

```
my @alpha = ( 'A', 'B, 'Y, 'Z' )
```

and I'm looking for `M`. That lest loose all sorts of optimisations that involve checks that may may the ordinary case much slower

Because of all of this it's by far the best solution to use a library or a language's built-in function to do all of this. In particular, Perl's hashes are usually all you need to check for specific strings and any associated data. The algorithm used is vastly better than a binary search for any non-trivial data sets

Wikipedia shows [this algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Iterative) for an iterative binary search

> The binary search algorithm can also be expressed iteratively with two index limits that progressively narrow the search range.
>
> ```
>    int binary_search(int A[], int key, int imin, int imax)
>    {
>      // continue searching while [imin,imax] is not empty
>      while (imin <= imax)
>        {
>          // calculate the midpoint for roughly equal partition
>          int imid = midpoint(imin, imax);
>          if (A[imid] == key)
>            // key found at index imid
>            return imid;
>          // determine which subarray to search
>          else if (A[imid] < key)
>            // change min index to search upper subarray
>            imin = imid + 1;
>          else        
>            // change max index to search lower subarray
>            imax = imid - 1;
>        }
>      // key was not found
>      return KEY_NOT_FOUND;
>    }
> ```

And here is a version of your code that is far from bug-free but does what you intended. You weren't so far off

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

print binarysearch( 76, 10 .. 99 ), "\n";

sub binarysearch {

    my $numbertolook = shift;
    my @intarray     = @_;
    my $lengthint    = scalar @intarray;
    my @sorted       = sort { $a <=> $b } @intarray;

    my $low   = 0;
    my $high  = $lengthint - 1;
    my $found = undef;
    my $midpoint;

    while ( $low < $high ) {
        $midpoint = int( ( $low + $high ) / 2 );

        #print $midpoint, " ",$low," ", $high, " ", @sorted, "\n";
        if ( $numbertolook < $sorted[$midpoint] ) {
            $high = $midpoint;
        }
        elsif ( $numbertolook > $sorted[$midpoint] ) {
            $low = $midpoint;
        }
        elsif ( $numbertolook == $sorted[$midpoint] ) {
            $found = 1;
            print "FOUND\n";
            return $midpoint;
        }

        if ( $low == $high - 1 and $low == $midpoint ) {
            if ( $numbertolook == $sorted[$high] ) {
                $found = 1;
                print "FOUND\n";
                return $midpoint;
            }
            return;
        }

    }

    return $midpoint;
}
```

#### output

```
FOUND
66
```

Answer (score 3):

You want

```
print $found, "\n";
```

Or

```
print $found . "\n";
```

With no operator between $found and the newline, it thinks $found is the filehandle to print a newline to, and is getting  an error because it isn't a filehandle.

Comment: Thank you :) Then the problem is that the subroutine doesn"t send the "found" value to the main thing when the number is present. it just ignores it :'(

Answer (score 1):

If you call print with several parameters separated with a space print expects the first one to be a filehandle. This is interprented as `print FILEHANDLE LIST` from the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html).

```
print $found "\n";
```

What you want to do is either to separate with `,`, to call it as `print LIST`.

```
print $found, "\n";
```

or to concat as strings, which will also call it as `print LIST`, but with only one element in `LIST`.

```
print $found . "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you.It worked :)  Now, if I can be evil and ask more, if i try to print the $found just before the end it gives me the "use of an uninitialized value" at the end. Could you help me there please?

Comment: What do you mean with "just before the end"?

Comment: just before the "return $found;" line :)

Comment: but the thing is that the function doesn't return "1", it gives me always "-1" and i really don't understand why :(

Comment: Then it didn't find the value in the array.

Comment: @bolav: As I understand it, the purpose of this exercise is to code a binary search in pure Perl. If you're going to involve `List::Util` at all then the program may as well just use `sort`.